# React native and React-native-agora - How to show ringing UI on mobile even if the app is killed and phone is locked?

Tags: react-native, agora.io

**React native and React-native-agora**

I don't exactly know the flow of Video calling in mobile apps. The flow which I am using for video calling is as follows:

1. User 1 taps to call User 2
2. Your app generates a unique name for a Room. Perhaps a combination of the two user's IDs.
3. User 1 connects to Room with generated unique name
4. Using FCM or GCM, send message of high priority with the unique name of the Room and token to User 2
5. **User 2 to receives notification and you display a ringing UI(even when the app is killed and phone is locked)**
6. User 2 accepts and connects to the same Room

Now I am stuck on point 5. I am sending the FCM notification(which shows up in tray (edit: now using voip notif) to user2 and now I need to show ringing UI on user2's mobile even if the app is killed and phone is locked. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues or errors are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried using a library like https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep?

Comment: @Samyak i tried but this library is for phone call not in app call

Comment: Hey. The callkeep library uses callkit for ios and connectionservice for android which is the recommended approach for having call functionality in Agora. The github even mentions that the library is meant for people who want to have VOIP calls. You can take a look at the following sample app https://github.com/wazo-platform/wazo-react-native-demo which uses the callkeep library along with webrtc. If you swap out the webrtc client they are using with Agora, you should be good to go.

Comment: @Muhammad Does this work for you?

Comment: @Samyak no its not work for me

Comment: Hey. Can you elaborate a bit more on why it is not working for you?

Comment: @MuhammadHaris have you got any solution regarding this ?

Comment: @Muhammad Does this work for you?